# Is there a way to get data from a json file and separate them with a tabulator?

Tags: python, finance, analysis

I decided to create a Python program to get financial data of a company (in this case Tesla). The following lines help me to get the cash and cash equivalents from 2021. The problem is that I need the data from the past 5 years. If I change the index of the `balance_sheet[0]` to `[1]` it won't do what I imagined it would do. Also, it would be really nice if the data from different years would be separated with a tabulator.

code:

```
cashAndCashEquivalents = balance_sheet[0]['cashAndCashEquivalents']
print(f"Cash And Cash equivalents of {company}:{cashAndCashEquivalents:,}")
```

output:

```
Cash And Cash equivalents of TSLA:19,384,000,000
```

Comment: What is `balance_sheet`? Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.